# How to get a reference to an enum class itself (not just a single case) as a class variable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

Basically, I want to create an abstract class and several child classes. Each child class will have their own distinct enum set, but I want to be able to reference the enum from the parent class. Something like

```
abstract class Parent {
    enum class TheEnum
}

class Class1: Parent() {
    enum class TheEnum(val value: String) {
        CASE_1("case 1"),
        CASE_2("case 2"),
        ...
}

class Class1: Parent() {
    enum class TheEnum(val value: String) {
        JANUARY("january"),
        FEBRUARY("february"),
        ...
}
```

Then I can have a function like `someFunction(enum TheEnum)`, and pass either `Class1`'s enum or `Class2`'s enum as an argument to it. This is the crux of what I need to accomplish, because I am passing many of these similar classes into the same functions, and rather than rewrite every single function for each class, I can just have one function.

Is there something like Swift's `TheEnum.self`?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you're searching for it's class. You can get Kotlin class by `TheEnum::class` and if you need it's Java class then `TheEnum::class.java`, also you can access each of them like `Class1.TheEnum::class` and `Class2.TheEnum::class`

Comment: What does `someFunction` actually do with the enum, since it can't know which type of enum it's actually receiving? Maybe you just need to create an interface that each of these enums implements and use that interface as the type parameter for `someFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No. In kotlin enum's don't inherit from each other and their instances and the value of their members is defined at compile time like so

```
enum class TheEnum(val value: String) {
    JANUARY("january"),
    FEBRUARY("february")
}
```

At runtime you cannot pass something like `TheEnum.JANUARY("december")` you can only pass `TheEnum.JANUARY`

Also since they can't inherit each other so it is just not possible to write a single function and pass different type of enums to them.

> Is there something like Swift's TheEnum.self?

Also no. Enums in kotlin can be compared like

```
enum class A {
  w, x
}

enum class B {
  y, z
}

fun let(a: A) {
  when(a) {
    A.w -> ""
    A.x -> ""
    B.y -> "" //warning: Comparison of incompatible enums 'A' and 'B' is always unsuccessful
    B.z -> "" //warning: Comparison of incompatible enums 'A' and 'B' is always unsuccessful
}
```

If you are in need of something more flexible you can take a look at [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html).